# Rails shared views between engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application with two engines, `EngineA` and `EngineB`. I want them to share the same views for a controller.
The problem is that if I put the shared views into `app/views` directory, rails will search them into `app/views/engine_a/controller` instead of `app/views/controller`.
I also tried to add a new view path using the `prepend_view_path()` method but rails still prepends the engine name when searching for the template.

TL;DR What's the easiest way to share views for a single controller between engines?

Comment: looking into double-colon :: syntax might be able to help you out